# How do I install the login screen from a minimal installation?

Tags: unity, installation

As construct ubuntu - unity environment from the minimum ubuntu - core then using apt-get install unity, I can not see the window to pop out to me to choose languages and other settings when login first time.

Anyone knows how to finish that if I want to custmize my image on our board?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [ubuntu-desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-desktop) [image: Install ubuntu-desktop] package, not just Unity.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want the 'login screen' for that you need:

```
apt-get install unity-greeter ubuntu-artwork
```

[image: Install via the software center]

If you want just a minimal desktop you need:

```
apt-get install -–no-install-recommends xorg xserver-xorg-core unity-2d gnome-session unity-common 
apt-get install -–no-install-recommends unity-lens-files unity-lens-applications unity-lens-music
apt-get install unity-greeter ubuntu-artwork
```

This was tested with a 12.04 server install. I'm using unity-2d because I want a server with a gui that I can remote-desktop to with a windows machine. If you don't care about that just replace 'unity-2d' with 'unity'